# Jenkins HockeyApp plugin not showing as Post Build Action

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hockeyapp

I have installed the HockeyApp plugin (v1.2.0) on Jenkins (v1.590), restarted Jenkins but the "Upload to HockeyApp" option is not showing in the list of post build actions.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with Jenkins v1.609 and HockeyApp plugin v1.2.0.

I got the plugin to work by upgrading Java to version 8 (installed as a homebrew cask).